# How to import correctly WinBox library in jest test?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs

I created a service which use [Winbox](https://github.com/nextapps-de/winbox) library. I imported it inside my angular service as written in the README and it works as expected:

```
import 'winbox';

declare const WinBox: WinBox.WinBoxConstructor;
export type WinBoxOptions = WinBox.Params;
```

I created this test:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { WinboxService } from './winbox.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import WinBox from "winbox";
export type WinBoxOptions = WinBox.Params;

jest.mock('winbox', () => {
 // Returns a function
 return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
   someMethod: () => {return WinBox}
 }));
})

@Component({ selector: 'app-welcome', template: '' })
class SimpleComponent {}

describe('WinBoxServiceService', () => {
 let service: WinboxService;
 let winBox: WinBox;

 beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [SimpleComponent],
     providers: [{ provide: WinBox, useValue: WinBox }],
   });
   service = TestBed.inject(WinboxService);
   winBox = TestBed.inject(WinBox);
 });

 it('should be created', () => {
   expect(service).toBeTruthy();
 });

 test('isThereAWinBox should be equal to true', () => {
   service.openWinBox({}, SimpleComponent);
   expect(service.isThereAWinBox).toBe(true);
 });
```

But unfortunately, when i execute service's tests, they failed with the following error:

```
WinBox is not defined
ReferenceError: WinBox is not defined
```

at this point inside the service:

```
openWinBox<ComponentInstance>(
    options: WinBoxOptions,
    component: Type<ComponentInstance>
    ): WinBoxContainer<ComponentInstance> {
    const winBox = new WinBox(options);

    // other code
    }
```

My actual configuration of jest is:
**test-setup.ts**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

**jest-config.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable */
const esModules = ['winbox', '@angular', '@ngrx'].join('|');
const { getJestProjects } = require('@nrwl/jest');
export default {
  displayName: 'angular-winbox',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/packages/angular-winbox',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    [`(${esModules}).+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$`]: 'babel-jest',
    '^.+.(ts|js|html|svg)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  resolver: '@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules}/)`],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
};
```

The versions of the libraries related to jest in my package.json are the following:

```
 "jest": "^27",
 "@nrwl/jest": "15.7.2",
 "@types/jest": "^27",
 "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27",
 "jest-preset-angular": "~11.1.2",
 "ts-jest": "^27",
```